# Delphi set thread to nil after starting it

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Today I have missed a lesson and I have found a really weird line of code that I cannot understand. This is the class:

```
type
 TMemoMessageThread = class(TThread)
  strict private
   FMemo: TMemo;
   FMemoMessage: string;
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
  public
   constructor Create(aMemo: TMemo);
   property MemoMessage: string read FMemoMessage write FMemoMessage;
 end;
```

Here I have created a class descending from TThread because I want to simulate a heavy computation. Look at the very simple UI.

[image]

You click the `Button2`"Create suspended" which creates a Suspended thread and then use this thread pressing `Button3`. This is the code:

```
constructor TMemoMessageThread.Create(aMemo: TMemo);
begin

 if (aMemo = nil) then
  raise Exception.Create('tMemo non valid!!!');

 inherited Create(True);
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
 FMemo := aMemo;

end;

procedure TMemoMessageThread.Execute;
begin

 Synchronize(procedure
             begin
              FMemo.Lines.Add('... process in parallel thread ...');
             end);

 Sleep(7000); //simulate something heavy to compute

 Synchronize(procedure
             begin
              FMemo.Lines.Add(FMemoMessage + '. Done! :)');
             end);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

 MemoMessageThread := TMemoMessageThread.Create(Memo1);
 MemoMessageThread.MemoMessage := 'Hello from TMemoMessageThread';
 Button3.Enabled := true;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 MemoMessageThread.Start;
 MemoMessageThread := nil; //why nil after start?
end;
```

As you can see, why is there a nil after the start? I really cannot understand. Since it is `FreeOnTerminate` shouldn't I ignore that line?

Comment: Just in case anybody else is wondering where the "nil" of which he talks actually is: There is a scrollbar for the source code and you have to scroll down to see the line in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `MemoMessageThread` to `nil` removes the reference to the instantiated object. The object still lives and executes, but the contact to the object is lost.

Since the thread is created with `FreeOnTerminate`, you should not use a reference to the object anyway. This is the only purpose of setting it to `nil` as I can see.

Comment: Hm ok. So it's not compulsory setting it to nil?Just good practice?

Comment: Definitely not compulsory.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi In this specific case, which is odd, the only reason I can think to set the reference to `nil` is if you intend to use `if Assigned(MemoMessageThread) ...` as a test to see if the thread has been created but not yet started.  This is a clumsy way to implement such a test, I'd say, though...

Comment: See it as a preventive measure. Adding a comment in code would perhaps have the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

In the scope of this limited example, there indeed is no point in nil-ling the reference. It doesn't do any harm either though.

The thread is created with `FreeOnTerminate` set, which means that once it has started, you must not access any of its properties again, because the thread might have already been terminated and freed. Nil-ling the reference makes sure that you cannot do that, and as such is not a bad idea, but isn't necessary as long as you remember to not access the started thread instance.